# Comparing the contents of two different lists

Tags: c++, list, iterator, containers

I am attempting to compare the contents of two different lists. I am using iterators to loop through the lists. I am checking to see if the last element in list 1 appears in list 2. Here is a snippet of the code

```
            /* This section will loop through the list to make sure that the line segment that was added to the 
             * contour path is updated to be visited
             */ 
            for(plf::colony<edgeLineShape>::iterator lineIterator = p_lineList->begin(); lineIterator != p_lineList->end(); lineIterator++)
            {
                edgeLineShape temp = *lineIterator;
                if(temp == *(pathContour.back()))
                {
                    lineSet = true;
                    lineIterator->setVisitedStatus(true);
                    break;
                }
}
```

pathContour is defined as `std::vector<edgeLineShape> pathContour`. This is the tricky part, I am comparing between two different containers. In fact two different datastructures. Thankfully thoguh the plf::colony data type satisfies the requirements for the C++ containers and what not.

When I go to compile, I ma given an error at the line:

```
if(temp == *(pathContour.back())
```

Here is the error at this line:

```
error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<edgeLineShape> >::value_type {aka edgeLineShape}')
```

My current understanding of the * operator for iterators is that it will dereference the iterator much like how pointers are dereferenced using the * operator?

Is this not correct?

Comment: `std::vector<T>::back()` does not return iterator. It returns reference to last element, so no need to dereference it with `operator*`

Comment: In addition: `*(pathContour.back()` leads to undefined behavior if `pathContour` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `back` returns a reference, not an iterator (note the error content: `(operand type is 'blablabla {aka edgeLineShape}')`). You can just compare it like normal:

```
if (temp == pathContour.back())
```

but really, `temp` isn't necessary, since you're only using it here, so you can do

```
if (*lineIterator == pathContour.back())
```

---

Also, if you're using C++11 or higher, you should look into `auto`, which can turn this:

```
for(plf::colony<edgeLineShape>::iterator lineIterator = p_lineList->begin(); lineIterator != p_lineList->end(); lineIterator++)
```

into this:

```
for (auto lineIterator = p_lineList->begin(); lineIterator != p_lineList->end(); lineIterator++)
```

or foreach, which can condense it down to the MUCH more concise:

```
for (auto lineIterator : p_lineList)
```

Comment: +1 for the recommendation on the condensing. I am actually using C++11. The auto use was never plain spelled out to me in the way that you did just now, thank you for that!

Comment: Marking as answered because this is the route that I went!

Answer (score 1):

As Semyon has mentioned, it is a reference so you can't simply use the derefence operator.

But, you can do this:

```
*(pathContour.end()--)
```

If you are stuck on using iterators.

Comment: Hmm, I do like that idea and it would certainly work but can anyone suggest another way of doing the same thing? Is this the best practice to use?

Comment: It would be better to use [std::prev](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) in that case.

Comment: what if pathCountour is empty?

Comment: @ROX thank you for pointing that out. In the example, we will assume that it is not empty but I will make sure to have checks to ensure that this doesn't happen when empty

Answer (score 1):

The code in your question isn't comparing containers. Perhaps this is an XY question?

The C++ic equivalent to your code is:

```
#include <algorithm>

auto it = std::find(p_lineList->begin(), p_lineList->end(), , pathCountour.back());
if (it != p_lineList->end()) { /* element found */ }
```

But possibly you should consider some other container that can avoid the linear search.